# I have an error with my following code.How can i solve that? i posted my coding and console part

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios7

CODING:

```
-(IBAction)regist:(id)sender
{

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.alvinchuastudios.com/aNSWERED/insert_user.php"]];
// create the Method "GET" or "POST"

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];


NSLog(@"the email is:%@",txtemail.text);
NSLog(@"the login is:%@",txtuser1.text);
NSLog(@"the pass is:%@",txtpass1.text);
NSLog(@"the last update by person is:%@",txtuser1.text);
NSLog(@"the user registered is:%@",datestr);
//Pass The String to server
   NSString *userUpdate =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"user_email=%@&@user_login=%@&@user_pass=%@&@last_upd_by=%@&user_registered=%@&",txtemail.text,txtuser1.text,txtpass1.text,txtuser1.text,datestr,nil];
    //NSString *userUpdate =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"user_email=gokul&@user_login=shyam&@user_pass=vaishak&@last_upd_by=shiva&user_registered=2014-01-07 16:18:43&",nil];
//Check The Value what we passed
NSLog(@"the data Details is =%@", userUpdate);

//Convert the String to Data
NSData *data1 = [userUpdate dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

//Apply the data to the body
[request setHTTPBody:data1];

//Create the response and Error

NSError *err;
NSURLResponse *response;

NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];

NSString *resSrt = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:responseData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

//This is for Response
NSLog(@"got response==%@", resSrt);

if(resSrt)
{
    NSLog(@"got response");
   /* ViewController *view =[[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:NULL];

    [self presentViewController:view animated:YES completion:nil];*/



}
else
{
    NSLog(@"faield to connect");
}



//ViewController *view =[[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:NULL];

//[self presentViewController:view animated:YES completion:nil];

[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];


}
```

CONSOLE STATEMENT:

```
the email is:shyam1303@gmail.com
the login is:ShyamSundar
the pass is:itdone
the last update by person is:ShyamSundar
the user registered is:2014-01-08 11:28:40
the data Details is =user_email=shyam1303@gmail.com&@user_login=ShyamSundar&@user_pass=itdone&@last_upd_by=ShyamSundar&user_registered=2014-01-08 11:28:40&
got response==Value1 : shyam1303@gmail.com, Value2: , Value3: , Value4: , Value5: 2014-01-08 11:28:40{"success":0,"message":"Required Fields are missing!"}
got response
```

Comment: OK I guess for starters, Steve, please tell us what your problem is instead of just "error with the following code"

Comment: Anyone can find out to insert the required field of data?

Comment: Just add some description of what you want

Comment: Yes.The problem is i want to insert the all the values in server through json post.i did that through above code.But it shows me the required fields are missing.i gave all the fields coorectly.

Comment: i want to add the missing fields in server.

Comment: Chnge your string with this NSString *userUpdate =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"user_email=%@&user_login=%@&user_pass=%@&last_upd_by=%@&user_registered=%@",txtemail.text,txtuser1.text,txtpass1.text,txtuser1.text,datestr];

Comment: Also the script is correct.So that i wrote the code.

Comment: the mismatch value are to be passed

Comment: Even i can got the response.But i cant figure out exactly how the fields missed?

Comment: In server these fields did not save

Comment: hello where is your url path dear??????

Comment: @"http://www.alvinchuastudios.com/aNSWERED/insert_user.php"

Comment: repost of [I have an error when i am posting strings in server through json in ios.It shows me required field are missing.How can i the correct response?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20987897/i-have-an-error-when-i-am-posting-strings-in-server-through-json-in-ios-it-shows)

Comment: i cant ask question and post any thing from stack over flow.they no longer to accept my question from my account.How can i overcome and again ask question?.Because i am new and beginner to stack overflow also to ios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just replace this coding

```
-(IBAction)regist:(id)sender
{

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.alvinchuastudios.com/aNSWERED/insert_user.php"]];
// create the Method "GET" or "POST"

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];



//Pass The String to server
NSString *userUpdate =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"user_email=%@&user_login=%@&user_pass=%@&  last_upd_by=%@&user_registered=%@&",txtemail.text,txtuser1.text,txtpass1.text,txtuser1.text,datestr,nil];
//NSString *userUpdate =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"user_email=gokul&@user_login=shyam&@user_pass=vaishak&@last_upd_by=shiva&user_registered=2014-01-07 16:18:43&",nil];
//Check The Value what we passed
 NSLog(@"the data Details is =%@", userUpdate);

//Convert the String to Data
NSData *data1 = [userUpdate dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

//Apply the data to the body
[request setHTTPBody:data1];

//Create the response and Error

NSError *err;
NSURLResponse *response;

NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];

NSString *resSrt = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:responseData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

//This is for Response
NSLog(@"got response==%@", resSrt);

if(resSrt)
{
 NSLog(@"got response");
/* ViewController *view =[[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:NULL];

  [self presentViewController:view animated:YES completion:nil];*/



}
else
{
NSLog(@"faield to connect");
}
```